Adding a DHCP reservation through entering device name
I am new to powershell. There may be better ways to acomplish what I am trying to do. I am writing a script to set a dhcp reservation when the user gives a device name. First the scopeID is searched for and saved in $newScope. It is also convert to an IP format. The same is done for the IP address and stored in $IP. It is also converted to an IP format. Finally the MAC is found and stored as a string in $MAC.
The issue is that I am trying to use those variables in the Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation command. If I input the information manually it works. How can I take the values that I found and input them into the respective fields.
viceName = Read-Host "Enter the name of the device" 
$PC= $DeviceName + ".domainname.com"
$DHCPServer = 'domainDHCPServer.com'


$scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $DHCPServer

#Get Scope
 $newScope = foreach ($scope in $scopes){
 
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer |
    Where-Object hostname -eq $PC |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ScopeID |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString

   }
   #Convert to IP format
   $newScope= [IPAddress]$newScope.Trim()

  #Get IP
 $IP = foreach ($scope in $scopes){
 
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer |
        Where-Object hostname -eq $PC |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString

   }
   #Convert to IP format
   $IP= [IPAddress]$IP.Trim() 
   
#Get Mac
$Mac = foreach ($scope in $scopes){
 
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer |
        Where-Object hostname -eq $PC |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty ClientID 
       
   }
   #Converts to String
   Out-String -InputObject $Mac

#Set Reservation

Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $newScope -IPAddress $IP -ClientID $Mac -ComputerName $DHCPServer 

The error I get says:

Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ScopeId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

I tried putting the variables striaght in and that did not work. I did a bunch of searching online and found similar issues but nothing specific to what I am trying to accomplish-putting variables in as property values.
Output for just the $newScope For Loop*******
I commented out the coversion to IP:
>      #Get Scope
>      $newScope = foreach ($scope in $scopes){
>      
>         Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer |
>         Where-Object hostname -eq $PC |
>             Select-Object -ExpandProperty ScopeID |
>             Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
>     
>        }
>     write-Output $newScope

OUTPUT: 192.168.x.x
I do get the scope in string format.
Thanks for all the help in advance!

Can you show the “manual” version that works, and can you describe what happens with your existing code? Is there an error message? Does it just silently fail? Does it create something with incorrect values?

When I say manual I mean  for example:  Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 -IPAddress 10.10.10.8 -ClientId "F0-DE-F1-7A-00-5E" -ComputerName DHCPServer.com

I edited my question to include the errot message.

What exactly does $newscope contain?

Note that $newScope= [IPAddress]$newScope.Trim() is not within any loop despite the indenting.

@mclayton ScopeId is not a string. It is an IPAddress. This are the propeties of the Get-DhcpSever4Leases:    [-ComputerName ]
[-ScopeId] 
[-AllLeases]
[-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
[-ThrottleLimit ]
[-AsJob]
[]

@js2010 $newScope has the scope of the lease in string format. Therefore inoder to convert it into an IP format I have to use the $newScope= [IPAddress]$newScope.Trim(). And no, is should not be in the for loop. I do not need to convert to an IP everytime it finds a lease. The conversion happens after I get the scope I am looking for.

@Mr.Puli - fair enough. i'll delete my comment to avoid distracting other readers. The error is definitely telling you that $newscope is $null (or empty) though - you might want to add some logging to check if / where it has a value and where it becomes null...

Why don't you put $newscope right before the last line, and tell us what it outputs?

Think of it this way: $newScope = 10.10.10.0 $IP=10.x.x.x, $Mac = "00-00-00-00-00-00". Now instead of using the IP addresses and string I want to use the variable name.

@js2010 I copied just the $newScope forloop to a different file and ran that. I comment out the coversion to IP and it does return the scope. I edited my above post to show what I ran to just get the scope.

I think the issue is that the property of the Add-DhcpServer4Reservation do not take variables as arguements. Hence I want to know how to pass variable( to be specific the contents of a variable) to a property. Its just that last line that I need help on.

In your original script, can you add write-host ($null -eq $newscope); write-host "newscope = '$(convertto-json -inputobject $newscope)'" on the line immediately before Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation and then post the output:

Okay now that show that ScopeId is null. That was helpful. Now I know that my scopID is getting lost somewhere. Atleast I have a lead now. I will check and get back. But please all input/ideas are welcomed. Also can you explain what your script did.

write-host writes text direct to the console and bypasses the pipeline (compared to write-output which writes values to the output stream, which might eventually end up displaying in the console if it doesn't get captured along the way). write-host ($null -eq $newscope) just outputs true or false depending on whether $newscope is $null`` or not, and convertto-json -inputobject $newscopeconverts$newscope``` to a json text representation.

After going through multiple revisions and research, I have finally got the script to work. Basically I had to convert the output of the forloops into the system.net.ipaddress for the scope and IP.  The following script is revised/working one. Thank you all for your input, it acutally helped. Cheers!
> $DeviceName = Read-Host "Enter the name of the device" 
$PC= $DeviceName + ".companydomain.com"
$DHCPServer = 'dhcpserver.com'


$scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $DHCPServer

#Get Scope
$newScope = foreach ($scope in $scopes){
 
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer | 
        Where-Object hostname -eq $PC | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty ScopeID 
   }

#Informative
write-host "The scope for" $PC "is" $newScope

#Convert to IP format
$TheScope = [System.Net.IPAddress]$newScope.Trim()


#Get IP
$IP = foreach ($scope in $scopes){

 
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer | 
        Where-Object hostname -eq $PC | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress 
   }

#Informative
write-host "The IP for" $PC "is" $IP

#Convert to IP format
$newIP = [System.Net.IPAddress]$IP.Trim()
 
#Get Mac
$Mac = foreach ($scope in $scopes){
 
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID -ComputerName $DHCPServer | 
        Where-Object hostname -eq $PC | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty ClientID     
   }
#Informative
write-host "The Mac for" $PC "is" $Mac


#Set Reservation

Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $TheScope -IPAddress $newIP -ClientID $Mac -ComputerName $DHCPServer 

